# read from csv file but that contains comma within text other than that used for separating text fields using c#

Tags: c#, csv

i am trying to read from csv file. this file is written through python code. the file is written in the below format:

```
"6.52213E+17,10/8/2015 20:03,\"Eye popping facts on status of eduction in PPP's Sindh, it seems attempt is to send masses back to stone age : https://t.co/dbVACyJVRf\",,27"
```

how can i separate this text:

```
6.52213E+17
10/8/2015 20:03
Eye popping facts on status of eduction in PPP's Sindh, it seems attempt is to send masses back to stone age : https://t.co/dbVACyJVRf\
27
```

i want to get these values in an array of string through c# code. when i try to split it through comma i also get splitted form of below text:

```
"Eye popping facts on status of eduction in PPP's Sindh, it seems attempt is to send masses back to stone age : https://t.co/dbVACyJVRf\"
```

Comment: Use a csv reader like the [`VisualBasic.TextFieldParser`-class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader)

Comment: did your code create that CSV? cause you can replace the delimiter.
I don't think you can assign a delimiter and also use it in the text and expect it to open as you wish.

Comment: Is this the real text or have you forgotten to remove the escape-backslashes? You have also added leading and trailing quotes, i'm pretty sure that those also don't belong to the real string. Show some sample lines not just a pseudo string literal.

Comment: i have already created csv file but now unable to read it

Comment: @TimSchmelter the text that i posted is read from a csv file and stored in variable. i want to separate text line but the string array stores each string separated by comma

Comment: actually this is twitter data that i stored in format

id_str,created_at,tweet_text,profile_location,Retweet_count